# Programmatically control storyboard tableview

Tags: ios, storyboard, height, tableview

I have a UItableview in storyboard, but when the user taps a button, I need to extend its height. The below code isn't working for me:

```
Self.tableview.height = #;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method of the UITableViewDelegate Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Try **turning off auto-layout** if it's enabled (it's ON by default). You can't set explicit sizes when using auto-layout, you can only manipulate that through constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Create local tableview reference in viewController

```
@property (nonautomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

now connect the this table view with the one in storyboard by holding the ctrl and drang from storyboard to the viewController tableview.

Now you can do what ever you want with your table - myTableView.